# Confused With Node Modules For Production

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a small extension plugin for use with Photoshop.
Part of the app I am using Firestore to store some user details.

I have installed the Firebase v9 SDK using `npm i firebase` and the app seems to be working fine so far.

When I packaged up the app, its now sitting at over 60mb in size which is due to everything in the node_modules folder. most of which I probably don't use.

Is there a way I can just use what I want from the node_modules folder and delete the rest?

Comment: What do you mean by 'packaged up the app' ?

Comment: When the app I am making is complete, I zip it up and send it to the user.

Comment: Usually you don't include the `node_modules` in the zip. Delete them and then zip rest of the src code. Users can them install node modules via `npm install` command